# Encapsulation of External API in Infrastructure Layer AS Persistence

Tags: domain-driven-design, abstraction, persistence, repository-pattern, onion-architecture

My question is about DDD, the Infrastructure layer, it's relation to the Domain, and specifically how we can take advantage of the ability to "swap out" one persistence implementation for another.

I have a .NET5 solution designed using Onion Architecture, that follows all of your basic guidelines:

- A Domain layer with zero dependencies to define the structure of the data you are moving from point A to point B
- An Application layer which defines the ways in which the data moves (queries and commands)
- An Infrastructure layer which implements those definitions
- And an API layer which exposes the application layer commands and queries

Usually, when examples of an Infrastructure layer are given, the persistence is implemented using a database. This makes a lot of sense because when you are creating a tutorial for creating microservices using onion architecture for each service, you want to have full control over your persistence layer so that years from now, it will still work.

But what about if you wanted to swap out the database for an external REST API? For example, if you have a base repository for a DB Context class with a function:

```cs
public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
{
    _dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return entity;
}
```

It is conceivable to swap out the DB context for a REST client like so:

```cs
public async Task<HttpResponse> AddAsync(T entity)
{
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<T>(CreateFormData(entity));
    return response;
}
```

(Where "CreateFormData" would return a FormUrlEncodedContent object created using the entity passed in.)

But as you can see, the return object has changed. Instead of passing back the entity, we need to pass the HttpResponse object, because it might have metadata that we need to use later on.

One example of this would be returning a list of items. The json returned from the http call will more than likely have paging data (the page number we are on, how many pages are left, etc.), and also response status info (error codes, success codes). Where can we encapsulate this? My first thought was to build it into the domain. So you would have a special entity for Response Status and a special entity for Paging data, and a Root object to contain those two, as well as the entity you are working with. But I don't think this is a proper use for the domain, because things like paging and http response data are implementation details. You'd never have a database with those objects as tables, and so they would not be part of any domain.

So where can we put these response wrappers? And how can we apply them so that the persistence is truly swap-able?

Here's a screen-cap of the relevant piece of my solution in Visual Studio:

[image]

Just want to add something pertaining to an answer from doubleYou.
I think the implementation should adhere to the restrictions imposed by the datasource. For instance, if the max count allowed by the rest API is 100, I don't think we should be chaining requests together to increase that amount and "fake" the response as a singular list when it was really many lists.
We should also utilize the tools that the datasource provides. If the default response list size is 10, but the API allows a query string to specify that we want 100, we should use that instead of making ten requests and chaining the responses together.

I think what I want is a wrapper specific to the implementation. Here's an example of what I'm thinking:

```
public record ResponseWrapper<T>(
    int PageNumber,
    int TotalPages,
    int PageSize,
    T[] Data
) where T : Entity;
```

Similarly, we could do the same with a request wrapper to provide the application with the options the datasource provides.

Comment: Your persistence layer is supposed to implement an interface from your domain layer. The returned object therefore cannot change. If your domain (emphasis on _domain_, this is not something that is decided by the technology you use) needs paging, then it should expose models or interfaces which allow your persistence layer to implement this paging.

Comment: Phrased differently, you stumble upon the conclusion that the returned object changed as if it was an inevitable consequence, but this statement is unsupported. Your HTTP implementation is responsible for converting the `HttpResponse` into domain objects.

Comment: @VincentSavard so basically, the function in my repository would not differ from persistence implementation to persistence implementation, but within the respective implementation, I would need to override said function to force it to be compatible with it. Am I on the right track?

Comment: That seems correct, yes.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see how far I can get with it.

Comment: So, if the idea is that the infrastructure only returns domain encapsulated data to the application, how can the the API receive any paging information? If for example, the client needed to retrieve a list of all items of a given type, it would be helpful for it to know if there are more rows in the set after making a request.
Without it, the only way to do the job would be to request until fewer than the requested count was returned. And in rare cases, that number could be zero.

Comment: Either the HTTP implementation of the repository handles the paging as an implementation detail, or you add the concept of paging to your domain, which will then allow the implementation to support it the way the domain needs it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129684/discussion-between-apriestley-and-vincent-savard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] things like paging and http response data are implementation details.

That's the key insight. Paging is not needed by your domain - otherwise you'd have implemented it in the database as well.

Let's say you have a repository interface such as this:

```cs
interface IReportRepository // or just `IReports`
{
    // May throw `RepositoryException`
    IEnumerable<Report> GetAllReports();
}
```

From your domain model's perspective, there's no such thing as getting only some of the data. If the model requests all reports via `GetAllReports()`, your `HttpReportRepository` has to find a way to provide them - otherwise, it's violating the contract.

It can do this by making a request for each page internally and combining the results. It also won't return anything related to HTTP. Any errors, including HTTP status code like 404 and 500, cause a `RepositoryException` to be thrown.

Here's an example of how this could look like:

```cs
class HttpReportRepository : IReportRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Report> GetAllReports()
    {
        var reports = new List<Report>();
        var page = 1;

        try {
            while (true) {
                // apiResult is basically your wrapper object
                var apiResult = _httpApi.GetReports(page);

                // deal with 404, 500, etc.
                if (apiResult.HttpStatus != 200) {
                    throw new RepositoryException();
                }

                // combine all reports
                reports.AddRange(apiResult.RetrievedEntities);

                // deal with API pecularities, such as paging
                if (page == apiResultData.PageCount) {
                    return reports;
                }

                page += 1;
            }
        } catch(SocketException ex) {
            throw new RepositoryException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Responding to your edit/comments:**

> I think the implementation should adhere to the restrictions imposed by the datasource.

No. The repository implementation must adhere to the contract defined by the domain model. The domain model should *not* consider the restrictions of the data source, because it does now "know" which data source(s) are used. That's the whole point.

As mentioned, you might want to deviate from this for practical considerations, but that's idea.

Your `ResponseWrapper` looks reasonable. In principle, the repository can be generic as well, but maybe it shouldn't be. Anyway, I think that's a separate question.

Comment: "Adhering to the contract of the domain model" is a great way to look at it - I appreciate that.
I don't think I'd ever provide a contract that promises to bring back ALL reports however. With a rest API data source it would take way too long to fulfill, and even with a traditional DB, I'd still want to enforce throttling. I believe it should be one page per contract in a GetList scenario. But in that case, the client still needs to know about the paging information.

Comment: Adding caching to your repositories *might* be an option. Otherwise, paging could become a domain concept. In this case, it's better if the model controls page size & page number, but perhaps your HTTP API makes this difficult. In that case, just return something that has all the data (entities, page infos). Sometimes it's better to be practical than dogmatic about these things.

Comment: I actually tried a domain based approach. The problem with this is that the payload for any list response comes back strongly typed. It will have paging info, status info, and data. But the key for data always reflects the type. If you request reports, it will come back as `reports: [{},{},{}]`. Other APIs might use a generic key, like `data: [{},{},{}]`, which I find way easier to work with in terms of deserialization. In the former case, the only way I know of is to have a wrapper domain model for each and every entity that can come back in a list.

Comment: To your point about caching, what would that look like in this situation? I can think of a few concepts.. like a database sitting in front of the external API, with a staleness timer, periodically refreshing itself. Sounds very complicated though. I wouldn't know where to begin.

Comment: Yes, caching always makes things complicated. It may or may not work for your case. I'm not sure I understand the 'strongly typed' problem. Basically, your repository returns a class with your reports and the page information. You can make this generic. Note that the model has nothing to do with deserialization - that's all done in the repository.

Comment: You wouldn't deserialize into your domain model? I've been doing: `_httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<TEntityListRoot>($"?{queryString}")` EntityListRoot containing paging info, response status info, and the list of resources. All of these are domain models, but I am still working on a way to refactor the non-resource entities to be implementation features. As it is right now, it's extremely difficult to maintain. I'm thinking about using Reactiveui/Refit to help with the complexity.

Comment: I'll try to clarify the strongly typed (maybe not accurate terminology) issue. Every list response that comes back from the datasource includes paging data. So if you create a wrapper to encapsulate that object, it would make sense to make it generic. (your wrapper contains the paging info, as well as a list<T> where T : any domain entity that can come back in a list. but the payload sting doesn't identify the resource list with a generic key, eg `data[]`. This makes deserialization of the payload to a generic class impossible afaik (but I don't know that much :) ).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've made an edit to address your clarification.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for sticking with me.
"The repository implementation must adhere to the contract defined by the domain model."
I understand, and after a few days of research, I think I agree. Seems like the conventional approach would be to apply your looping http logic. And if I want to constrain traffic, do it inside a contract resolver in the app layer. Client asks the query handler for a billion rows, resolver says "no, but here, you can have 100". Repository implementation doesn't care. He just takes instructions and follows through.

Comment: That being the case, would it follow that pagination is not a persistence detail after all? If the infrastructure API provides metadata, I should simply strip it off and only provide domain objects to the handler. I can build my own pagination wrapper once the data comes down the chain.
I am not sure how I would supply something like total row count. I would only be able to supply info on A: what the client requested (num rows, start index), and B: resulting metadata (how many rows actually came back)

Comment: If you want to limit the number of entities a user can work with at a time, that might be a business rule and could influence the repository contract. There could be a `int Count()` method. Ideally, this shouldn't be dictated by your web API, but of course it might be in practice: if the repository simply can't be implemented in terms of the web API, I'd prioritize completing the project over having a conceptually clean repository interface.

Comment: Agreed! I already have a working version of the specific feature that was requested. The clean repository implementation is more preparation for additional features. I'm attempting to build up a solid foundation to keep my bases covered. There are other services that we use as well to which I could apply these same strategies to be able to swiftly add new features. I've successfully stripped off metadata using a custom JSON converter, so the plan now is to find a way to make the httpclient act like a db context.